# KivyMD icons of the TopAppBar are white rectangles

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to add a topbar to the GUI im creating with KivyMD. When i run the program I'm supposed to get a menu icon on the top left hand corner of the topapp bar but instead i'm getting a white rectangle. I figured its because of the parent Label tag inside the kv file. When i remove it, it works. Does anyone know why this is the case? What does the label tag have to do with the icon?

**python file(reduced version):**

```
 #import kivy
 import os
 os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
 from kivymd.app import MDApp

 from kivy.animation import Animation
 from kivy.uix.image import Image
 from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.label import Label
 from kivy.uix.button import Button
 from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
 from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
 from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
 from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
 from kivy.lang import Builder
 from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
 from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,SwapTransition
 from kivy.core.window import Window
 from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
  
 from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
 from kivymd.app import MDApp
 Window.size=(300,600)
 class Homescreen(Screen,MDApp):
     def menu(self):
        print("navigation")

 kv=Builder.load_file("remy.kv")
 sm=ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
 sm.add_widget(Homescreen(name="homescreen"))
 sm.transition.duration=0.01
 sm.current="homescreen"

 class remy(MDApp):
    def build(self):
    Window.clearcolor=(240/255,128/255,128/255,1)
    return sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    remy().run()
```

**kivy file:(reduced version)**

```
#:kivy 2.2.1
<Label>:
    font_name:"Segoeprb"
<Homescreen>:
    name:"homescreen"
 
    MDBoxLayout:
       orientation: "vertical"
       md_bg_color: "#1E1E15"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"
        anchor_title: "left"
        left_action_items: [["menu"]]

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
```